# JDBC connection string for SQL DW

Tags: sql, azure, jdbc, access-token, data-warehouse

how can i use access token in JDBC connection string to connect to Azure SQL DW ?

Comment: Hi @Whiplash, welcome to stack overflow! If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this Azure tutorial: [Connecting using access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-using-access-token):

- Applications/services can retrieve an access token from the Azure
  Active Directory and use that to connect to Azure SQL Database/Data
  Warehouse.

The example below contains a simple Java application that connects to Azure SQL Database/Data Warehouse using access token-based authentication.

Code example:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

// The azure-activedirectory-library-for-java is needed to retrieve the access token from the AD.
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;

public class AADTokenBased {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Retrieve the access token from the AD.
        String spn = "https://database.windows.net/";
        String stsurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/..."; // Replace with your STS URL.
        String clientId = "1846943b-ad04-4808-aa13-4702d908b5c1"; // Replace with your client ID.
        String clientSecret = "..."; // Replace with your client secret.

        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(stsurl, false, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
        ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(spn, cred, null);
        String accessToken = future.get().getAccessToken();

        System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);

        // Connect with the access token.
        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();

        ds.setServerName("aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name.
        ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database name.
        ds.setAccessToken(accessToken);

        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection(); 
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTH.